# Struggling to convert for loop into do..while loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm struggling to convert a for loop into a do..while loop, seems like an unnecessary exercise to me but maybe it'll  be useful to me later on. I can't get my head round how I'd re-design it, I can pretty easily put it into a while loop but not a do..while.

The for loop is below;

```
    int d;
    int n = 55;

    for (d = 0; n != 0; d++)
    {
        n /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(d);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Use prefer to use `while(true) { ... }` (which is pretty much what the `loop` keyword in Rust does) if a for-loop does not fit my needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
 int d=0;
 int n = 55;
 do{ 
  n /= 10;
  d++;
 }while(n != 0);
 System.out.println(d);
```

all loops are the same, basically they need a `condition`. in your case your condition is `(n!=0)`. `for` loop is good because its 'tidier'.

Comment: All loops are not the same. Do/while loops are fundamentally different from the others. They execute at least once.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do:

```
    int d = 1;
    while ((n /= 10) != 0) {
        d++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without `do`..`while`/`while` but a simple infinite loop (which has the greatest flexibility):

```
int d = 0;
int n = 55;
// loop
while (true) {
    n /= 10;
    d++;
    //break condition
    if (n == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int d;
int n = 55;

d = 0;
do {
    n /= 10;
    d++;
} while(n != 0)

System.out.println(d);
```

this way the `d` variable, which just count how many times the loop is executed, will be updated the same way as the for loop would do.

Note that this will work only if n is not 0 at the beginning of the loop. In other words, if n is set to 0 in the second line of code the result will be different from the for loop, because the do..while loop always gets executed at least once, therefore the output would be 0 in the "for loop" case and 1 in the "do..while loop" case.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it with a `do...while` loop like

```
int d = 0;
int n = 55;

do {
    n /= 10;
    d++;
} while (n != 0);
System.out.println(d);
```

But I would suggest you use [`Integer.toString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) and take the length of the resulting `String` instead like,

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(n).length());
```